# Why does NSArray of UIImageViews follow a certain pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I have an array of 4 `UIImageViews` A, A2, A3 and A4. I want them to be dragged on to another `imageView` called answerA. Every time I drag one of them on the answer it should change the image on answerA to a number which tells how many were dragged on it. E.g. If i drag A on answerA then answerA image will change to number 1. If i drag one more A from the array then it will change to number 2. For some reason my array follows a strange pattern. The first one i drag changes to number 1, the second one does nothing, the third one will change to number 2 and the fourth will change it back to number 1. No matter in which order i drag them it will always be in same pattern.

This is my array of 4 `imageViews`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *letterA; //initialized in .h

self.letterA =  @[A, A2, A3, A4];//initialized in .m
```

My method to check collision:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    int intersectionCount = 0;
    for (UIImageView *letter in letterA) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame)) {
            letter.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            letter.hidden = YES;
            intersectionCount++;
        }
    }

    if (intersectionCount == 1) {
        UIImage *Pic1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number1.png"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic1];
    }
    else if (intersectionCount == 2) {
        UIImage *Pic2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number2.png"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic2];
    }
    else if (intersectionCount == 3) {
        UIImage *Pic3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number3.png"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic3];
    }
    else if (intersectionCount == 4) {
        UIImage *Pic4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number4.png"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic4];
    }
```

NOTE: correctCounterA is a small `imageView` on top of answerA so that only that small section would change the image to numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modified `touchesEnded` as like below. here you are finding drag image in wrong way. may this help you.

```
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

        for (UIImageView *letter in letterA) {

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame)) {
                letter.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                letter.hidden = YES;
                intersectionCount++;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (intersectionCount == 1) {
            UIImage *Pic1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number1.png"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic1];
        }
        else if (intersectionCount == 2) {
            UIImage *Pic2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number2.png"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic2];
        }
        else if (intersectionCount == 3) {
            UIImage *Pic3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number3.png"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic3];
        }
        else if (intersectionCount == 4) {
            UIImage *Pic4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number4.png"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic4];
        }
}
```

**Edit** : According to your requirement, you need to declare `intersectionCount` in `.h` file and in `viewDidLoad`, you need to assign as below.

```
int intersectionCount = 0;
```

and Change `touchesEnded` like as above.

Comment: This solved the strange pattern problem but now they dont act like i need them to. If I drag A4 first then the image will change to number 4 instead of number 1. Is there a way to make it so it wont matter in which order they are dragged?

Comment: @Laury, check my edited answer and once again replace touchEnded method. may this solved your problem.